# Placeholder won't ellipsize using react-native-picker-select

Tags: javascript, npm, react-native

I am using [RNPickerSelect](https://github.com/lawnstarter/react-native-picker-select) with custom styling (using [styled-components/native](https://www.styled-components.com/)). However, since the property useNativeAndroidPickerStyle is set to false, texts that are too long do not ellipsize, but move to the right.

After setting useNativeAndroidPickerStyle to true, the text does ellipsize, but the styling is lost. Adding `textInputProps={{numberOfLines: 1}}` doesn't seem to solve the problem, either, as it is just ignored. Adding the numberOfLines property to the styled component, but it throws an error, as this is not a styling property.

The pickdr is coded as follows

```
<RNPickerSelect
          placeholder={{
            label: `${i18n.t('selectABoard')}`,
            value: null,
          }}
          items={items}
          onValueChange={
            value => {
              if (value != null && value !== selected) {
                if (boards.find(board => board.name === value.name)) {
                  onBoardSelected(value);
                } else {
                  onCommitteeSelected(value);
                }
              }
            }
          }
          value={selected}
          style={stylesPicker}
          Icon={() => (
            <IconContainer>
              <Entypo
                name="chevron-down"
                color={colors.PRIMARY_BLUE}
                size={20}
              />
            </IconContainer>
          )}
          useNativeAndroidPickerStyle={false}
          textInputProps={{numberOfLines: 1}}
        />

const stylesPicker = StyleSheet.create({
  placeholder: {
    color: colors.PRIMARY_BLUE,
  },
  inputIOS: {
    color: colors.PRIMARY_BLUE,
    height: NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
  },
  inputAndroid: {
    color: colors.PRIMARY_BLUE,
    height: NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
    paddingLeft: 16,
    paddingRight: 16,
  },
  iconContainer: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    height: NAVBAR_HEIGHT,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingRight: 16,
  }
});
```

[The whole text is "Nahual Prueba NGO - Finance Committee", the expected placeholder should be something like "Nahual Prueba NG..."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpoeB.png)